# Joomla y bases de datos

Tags: sql, web, joomla3

Estoy apunto de comenzar un proyecto y me he encontrado con joomla, pero me pregunto si es posible usar SQL con joomla ?  el proyecto pertenece a una empresa la cual difícilmente cambiara sus Gestores de base de datos, así que quisiera asegurarme de que SQl es compatible con joomla.

Comment: SQL es el lenguaje de algunas bases de datos, dime que tipo de base de datos usan? El Joomla por defaul usa MySQL pero se que es compatible con otras. Saludos.

Comment: en especifico este proyecto se llevara con SQL Server 2008 como manejador de base de datos gracias por la ayuda

Comment: las bases de datos que maneja excactamente son : MySQLLI
MySQL (PDO)
POSTGRE sql